# Html5 audio return error MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED after 6 audio loaded in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, audio

i need to load near 20 sounds on my page. i thought maybe i need to load only 2 element separately so that's why you will see inProgress property

```
loadAudio: function () {
        if (this.inProgress <= 1) {
            this.inProgress++;
            var elem = this.audioQueue.pop();
            if (elem != null) {
                var path = elem.Path + elem.Fileid + ((this.canPlayMp3) ? '.mp3' : '.wav');

                audio = new Audio();
                audio.src = "http://localhost:55578/~/x.mp3";
                audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function (e) { AudioPlayer.audioLoaded(e); }, false);
                //audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', function (e) { AudioPlayer.audioLoaded(e); }, false);
                audio.addEventListener('error', function (e) { AudioPlayer.audioLoaded(e); }, false);
                if (elem.AudioType == AudioPlayerTypes.Keyboard) {
                    this.keyboardAudio[elem.Id] = audio;
                }
            }
        }



 audioLoaded: function (e) {
        var t = e.target;
        if (e.type == "error") {
            var code = e.target.error.code;

            console.log("error" + t.currentSrc + e.target.error.code);
        } else {
            console.log("loaded" + t.currentSrc);
        }
        this.inProgress--;
        this.loadAudio();
    }
```

As you can see i am loading the same sound just for test but the same problem after 6 audio i got error

```
LOG: loadedhttp://localhost:55578/~/x.mp3 
LOG: loadedhttp://localhost:55578/~/x.mp3 
LOG: loadedhttp://localhost:55578/~/x.mp3 
LOG: loadedhttp://localhost:55578/~/x.mp3  
LOG: loadedhttp://localhost:55578/~/x.mp3  
LOG: loadedhttp://localhost:55578/~/x.mp3  
LOG: errorhttp://localhost:55578/~/x.mp3 (4 - is error code)
```

it works pretty cool in Chrome, Firefox but not in IE.
I cant find any limitations, and solutions.

Also additional question: I read that some times is better avoid DOM elements so thats why i am workin with audio object because i need to play different elements lots of times.

Comment: An error code of `4` would mean "the resource is not suitable" though all are the same MP3, so I'm not sure why it's raising that error. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-mediaerror-media_err_src_not_supported

Comment: yes its the main pain for me because i am loading the same element. it look like that in ie total audio streams are limited to 6 or what...

Comment: Which version of IE? I assume 9? What if you try and load 5 audio streams, does that work? Also, do you have Media Player installed?

Comment: Yes its IE9. Also i have WMP installed because i can play sounds this which are loaded.

Comment: And yes 5 audio streams works pretty cool but some times it loads more than 6 sounds but its like a random.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its really strange, generally error is correct because IE Doesn't have free resources.
On my laptop was issue with charger, computer was really slow, and today i changed it, and computer works faster and sounds are loaded in explorer properly :)

Comment: What? Your laptop charger fixed your HTML audio error?

Comment: @Michael yes it was long time ago, I assume it was related to battery configuration if laptop is not charging it was slowing down PC to last longer